# Circle Corner Collision Behavior

Tags: collision, geometry, game-physics

I am working on a project where I have a rolling marble in 2D. I can detect when the marble hits the corner of a box but I can't figure out what behavior it should have when it hits the corner. I need to figure out how to reposition the ball so it doesn't overlap the box. With a box to box collision it is as easy as setting the boxes right next to each other but for a circle and box I don't know where to move the marble to so it looks realistic.

I am not asking how it bounces off. I do have a good understanding of trig. As you move the marble towards the box it will, at some point, come to overlap with the box. I need to know how to make it so they don't overlap anymore but so it still looks realistic. It does not need to bounce off (like assuming infinite mass on part of marble).

Comment: Do you have a basic understanding of trigonometry?

Comment: Are you asking "how does a marble bounce when it collides with a corner?"?

Answer (score 1):

Take a good look at this article on Wikipedia: [Elastic Collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-_and_three-dimensional).

You will need to create surface normals for your 2D objects at any given surface point, which will be problematic if your boxes are *perfectly* square, as sharp edges don't have normals. You will have to give the corner cases (no pun intended) special treatment and give them surface normals that are the average of the normals of the two lines that join at the corner.

Basically, use vectors.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I don't need to have the marble "bounce" off. I just need it to not overlap the block, which means moving it to a location so that the marble touches the box but doesn't overlap it.

Comment: Well, that's a different question. If you can detect collisions, why are you unable to detect corner collisions? You might have to rethink your code a little.